# How to access an element by xpath?

Tags: python, selenium

How to access an element on pic: `'captcha__human__submit-description'` in a frame using xpath. I need to check the presence of this element, and depending on its presence, continue or terminate the program.
this combination does not find this element:

```
driver.switch_to(0)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//dic[@class='captcha__human__submit-description']").text
```

[xml data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0RDg.png)

Comment: ``//dic[...`` should probably be ``//div[...``

Comment: Post text, not images. We can't experiment on images.

Comment: @mike-scotty //dic[... a typo, but no, that's not the reason...

Answer (score 0):

try to switch it like this :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@onload='iframeOnload()']"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='captcha__human__submit-description']").text
```

or with **explicit waits** :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@onload='iframeOnload()']")))
some_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='captcha__human__submit-description']"))).text
print(some_text)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

As already given by CruisePandey, you can switch to frame and then access element using the XPaths. However, I believe you can also use CSS Selectors to do the same thing.

Using Selenium 3 -

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.captcha__human_submit-description")
or
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.captch__human__container > div:nth-child(2)")
```

Using Selenium 4 Beta version

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.captcha__human_submit-description")
or
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.captch__human__container > div:nth-child(2)")
```